# WSO2 MB 2.2.0 Server down randomlly

Tags: wso2, messagebroker, wso2-message-broker

I have installed WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 and WSO2 MB 2.2.0 in same machine.
Both products have been configured with MySQL for Carbon tables.
I run the products with offset 0 for ESB and offset 1 for MB.
The installation is correctly and the communication between MB and ESB operating correctly.
The problem is than MB shutdown randomly and I have to rerun MB.
I have tried with Linux and Windows servers, and I have the same problem.
Can anybody help me?

**Update: Error Information**
malloc: Cannot allocate memory

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000000009, pid=3699, tid=140567970445056

JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_55-b13) (build 1.7.0_55-ockbuild_2014_04_16_12_11-b00)
 Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 C  0x0000000000000009

Core dump written. Default location: /u01/app/wso2mb-2.1.1/core or core.3699

An error report file with more information is saved as:
 /tmp/jvm-3699/hs_error.log

./wso2server.sh: line 299:  3699 Aborted                 (core dumped)

Answer (score 0):

Do you get error logs when the server go down? If so please share.

Also, how much memory have you allocated for ESB and MB server instances respectively? May be, the servers do not have enough memory to run. So please double check on the memory allocation.

Comment: In both products I have configured 
 -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
The ESB is working without problem.
The MB only show this message
[malloc: Cannot allocate memory]
And I not have see any error in logs files.

Comment: I have updated the question with the error information